# 301 redirect via htaccess rules on the new site

Tags: redirect

Old site: abc.com
New site: abc.org

The old site, abc.com, is only a "parked site" now, so there is no .htaccess files any more for that domain name.

So all htaccess rules need to be in the .htaccess file on the new domain name, abc.org.

Can someone please help me with the rules so that all .COM urls gets forwarded to the .URL equivalent URL...??

So for example, if someone goes to abc.com/dir1/dir2/aboutus.php then they will be redirected to the same URL but on the new domain, abc.org/dir1/dir2/aboutus.php

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is Domain Name Forwarding, and it CAN NOT be done using .htaccess of the target domain. If you are using godaddy to register your domain, here is a guide that they have prepared for people who would want to forward one domain to another:

https://ph.godaddy.com/help/manually-forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name-422

The process is about the same for other domain name registrars. You have 2 options when doing the domain forwarding. One is to keep showing the original domain, such as abc.com in your example. This is Forwarding with Masking. The other option is to forward abc.com to abc.org and the user sees abc.org in the browser. This is Forwarding without Masking.

Comment: Thanks. hostmonster.com does not offer this option, so I need to abandon setting this up as I had envisioned it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !examplenew.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.examplenew.org/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Sagar but, unfortunately, this is not working.  Here are the contents of my .htaccess file: `# Use PHP5.6 as default

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php

# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.org/$1 [L,R=301] `

Comment: Try this

`# Use PHP5.6 as default AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php # BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.org$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.org/$1 [L,R=301] 
</IfModule> `

Comment: Sagar. My apologies. I had cut-and-pasted the wrong .htaccess file.  Here is the actual one. Seems like the code that you had sent is already present in the .htaccess file. `# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 
#END WordPress
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old_domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old_domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.new_domain\.org\/$1" [R=301,L]`

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: Please don't use the comment section to write long CODE, update the  question with new CODE and then update the answer accordingly.